# string and class are both reference type, then why the comparasion returns different result?

Tags: c#

I'm comparing 2 strings and 2 class objects, then why string one comparison gives results "TRUE", whereas objects comparison give "FALSE"? Please explain whats going in term of memory locations in both teh case?

```
class Program
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s1 = "xyz";
        string s2 = "xyz";

        bool b = s1 == s2;

        Person p1 = new Person();
        Person p2 = new Person();

        bool x = p1 == p2;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (== and !=) are defined to compare the values of string objects, not references.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Clear explanation on the "==" operator on [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In short, the function of the equality operators is different.  Basically, for a string, the == operator will look at each character and if it matches, and for general reference types the == operator will see if they have the same 'pointer'.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to overload `==` and `!=` operators for your `Person` class if you want something else than the default behavior for reference types (which is to return `True` if and only if instances are the same ([except for the string class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx))):

```
public class Person
{

    public static bool operator ==(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
        // Insert logic here
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
        // Insert logic here
    }
}
```

In your example, as you instantiate two different `Person` objects, `p1 == p2` will returns false.